# Prove the following for linear map $S$ such that $S^2=S$

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $W$ be finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $S : W \rightarrow W$ be a linear map such that $S^2 = S$. Now I have to show that-

> $v\in R(S)$ iff $S(v)=v$ and every $v\in S$ can be uniquely written as $a+b$ where $a\in R(S)$ and $b\in N(S)$.

My attempt: For the first part, $S(v)=v\implies S^2(v)=S(v)=v$. Thus $v\in R(S)$. Now I can't show if $v\in R(S)$, then $S(v)=v$. How to do that?

Also, for the other part, Let some vector is written as $v=a+b$. Then $S(v)=S(a)+S(b)=S(a)$ since $S(b)=0$. So, $S(v)=a$ and $b=v-a=v-S(v)$. Now how to show the uniqueness of this map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$v\in R(S)$ $\implies$ There exists $u\in V$, such that $S(u)=v$. Then $S(v)=S^2(u)=S(u)=v$.

Every $v\in V$ can be written as $v=S(v)+(v-S(v))$, then $S(v)\in R(S)$ and $(v-S(v))\in N(S)$, since $S(v-S(v))=S(v)-S^2(v)=0$.

Now if $v$ can be written as $v=a+b$ for some $a\in R(S)$ and $b\in N(S)$, then you have already shown that $a$ has to be $S(v)$ and $b$ has to be $v-S(v)$. Thus you have proved uniqueness already.